# Why does while loop sometimes exit before exit condition is met?

Tags: c, while-loop

I need to create a string of variable length composed of random characters, so I built a function that does just that, however, after executing it a few times I noticed that the while loop stops executing even though the condition is still not met at first I had (j < taille) but then I changed it to (j <= taille ) but I still have the same problem , sometimes it doesn't execute normally
here's my code:

```
void gener_observation(char num[b])
{
    int taille,i,j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    taille = (rand()%(b-40)) + 1;
    j=0;
    i=0;
    while(j <= taille)
    {
        i = ((rand()%26) + 65 );
        num[j] = i;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `b`?  Is it a global?  What is its value when this function is called?

Comment: Aside: move `srand(time(NULL));` out of the function to the beginning of `main().` Also, if you intend to "create a string" then you must write a nul terminator to it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. The best way to do that is by copy/paste, after you check it does exhibit the behaviour described. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: b is a global that is equal to 100

Comment: @WeatherVane I just saw your comment and added a null terminator and I think the problem is solved thank you

Answer (score 0):

Turn your code into this:

```
void gener_observation(char num[b])
{
    int taille,i,j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    taille = (rand()%(b-40)) + 1;
    j=0;
    i=0;
    printf("The value of taille equals [%d]", taille);
    while(j <= taille)
    {
        printf("Currently, j equals [%d]", j);
        i = ((rand()%26) + 65 );
        num[j] = i;
        j++;
    }
    printf("Finished");
}
```

... and run your code again. As your code contains a random number, it might be different for all of us, but using the printed results, you might find out the problem you're having.

Comment: so b is a global currently =100

Comment: I have tried doing that and an example of when the code doesn't work is when taille =15 and the loop stop when j=11 ,it doesnt run for the values (12,13,14) and num would have weird characters in the end

Comment: When taille=15, then your loop should not stop when j did not reach 12 yet. Are you sure your application isn't crashing? (I added a "Finished" line, can you check if you see that line? In case not your application might not be stopping, but crashing instead.

Comment: yes, I just checked again with the "finished" line and I still have the same problem

Comment: I just realized that the code added characters to num (other than those that were generated using taille) so the loop worked fine :'), the problem was actually the fact that I didn't add a null terminator at the end. So I would like to thank you for your help

Comment: I'm glad my answer was useful :-)